# Can't deploy service on google cloud

Tags: python, api, web-services, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to publih my flask api using google cloud terminal.

I am getting this error after a while after entering "gcloud app deploy" on google cloud terminal

```
 {\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",
  \"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",
  \"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,
   \"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",
   \"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",
   \"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\", 
   \"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/<MYAPPNAME>/regions/europe-west1/autoscalers\",
    \"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}
```

I gave these permissions to myself:

[image: I]

Comment: try runnig `gcloud app deploy --log-http --verbosity:debug` and share the output with us

Comment: I solved it by adding some settings to app.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed app.yaml and added

```
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 7
```

to it. It solved the problem!